# Applied for US B2 visa and don't want to continue

Tags: visas, usa, esta, us-visa-waiver-program, b1-b2-visas

I recently applied for the US B2 visa and have an interview coming up. However I have now realised how difficult it is to be accepted for this visa as a U.K. citizen. I want to cancel the interview which I know is possible, but will cancelling and not rescheduling an appointment affect me using the ESTA waiver programme in future as I know I am eligible for this? I know illl lose the visa fee I paid but that isn't a problem

Comment: Why do you think it would be difficult to be accepted?

Comment: I echo @phoog's comment; I'm a UK citizen, and I have a B1/B2 visa (and have for many years).  I know others who have them, too.  As long as you have some kind of sane reason for wanting one (and don't have any of those nasty skeletons in the closet that make US entry difficult) I wouldn't anticipate any problems.

Comment: Why would being a UK citizen make it difficult? I mean sure, most UK citizens don't bother and travel under the VWP, but I can't see what prejudice the US would have.

Comment: I was told that it's particularly difficult for a U.K. Citizen to get a B2 visa because I'm eligible for the VWP. I want to go to the US to go backpacking and explore the country, I felt that 6 months would better for me to do that, but others have said the B2 would be difficult to get for that.

Comment: @DeeBrown There's no reason the existence of the VWP makes it more difficult to get a visitor visa. It's almost certainly easier for a UK citizen than say, a Nigerian citizen. However, as with all visa applications what you're proposing needs to make sense and be within your means.

Comment: If you withdraw your visa application and travel on the VWP, you should expect that you'll simply have to go through the additional scrutiny _at the border_ rather than _at the consulate_ (which is much more relaxed). At this point you may as well go through with the visa process, assuming you can actually afford the holiday and can show a reason you will return to the UK.

Answer (score 3):

Grounds for ineligibility for the visa waiver program include having been denied a visa.  If you withdraw your application, you cannot be denied a visa, so you will preserve your eligibility (assuming you aren't ineligible for some other reason).

It might be a good idea to withdraw your application formally rather than just to cancel your interview and not reschedule.

You should also keep in mind that if you visit using the VWP you will of course be subject to the slightly more restrictive terms of that program.  For example, your stay will be limited to 90 days.

Comment: Sure, it seems **unlikely**, but say we heard from an insider "Yes, the US keeps a list of people who applied for visas and 'mysteriously' dropped the application.." that would **not be surprising**, right?  I think it would be impossible to truly answer the question if the action in question puts you on "some sort of list": but sure, on the face of it, it should be no problem.